# Can you block command line prompt but allow Python?

Tags: python

I want to block users for using the command prompt, but I also want to allow them to use Python. However, Python has the `os` module which users can use to execute commands, like:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen("command to be run eg start "C:/")
```

How can I stop Python from allowing `os.popen` (above) to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be looking for a full sandbox, and not just preventing `os` from being imported.

For instance, you can use [RestrictedPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/) for blocking imports.

Or you can set `sys.modules['os']=None`. Look at this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules) for more options.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of blocking, you could allow users to run python in a "jail". They would be able to run commands, but in a safe sandbox.